# Multiline progress bars

Tags: command-line, progress-bar

I know that to update something like a progress bar on the command line, one uses '\r'.  Is there any way to update multiple lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use some existing library like ncurses. But you may try dirty workaround by clearing console with system call: `system("cls");`.

Comment: Is system("cls") Windows-only?

Comment: OS X core Darwin is Unix compliant and it should have "clear" along with other Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Python try using [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/). It's a really intuitive wrapper around curses.

Simple example:

```py
from blessings import Terminal

term = Terminal()

with term.location(0, 10):
    print("Text on line 10")
with term.location(0, 11):
    print("Text on line 11")
```

If you're actually trying to implement a progress bar, consider using
[progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.3-dev). It will save you a lot of `\r` cruft.

You can actually connect blessings and progressbar together. Try running this:

```py
import time

from blessings import Terminal
from progressbar import ProgressBar

term = Terminal()

class Writer(object):
    """Create an object with a write method that writes to a
    specific place on the screen, defined at instantiation.

    This is the glue between blessings and progressbar.
    """
    def __init__(self, location):
        """
        Input: location - tuple of ints (x, y), the position
                        of the bar in the terminal
        """
        self.location = location

    def write(self, string):
        with term.location(*self.location):
            print(string)


writer1 = Writer((0, 10))
writer2 = Writer((0, 20))

pbar1 = ProgressBar(fd=writer1)
pbar2 = ProgressBar(fd=writer2)

pbar1.start()
pbar2.start()

for i in range(100):
    pbar1.update(i)
    pbar2.update(i)
    time.sleep(0.02)

pbar1.finish()
pbar2.finish()
```

[image: multiline-progress]

Comment: This is perfect! Small update: the current version of `progressbar` wants the file handle to have a `flush()` method too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VT100 codes](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~shuford/terminal/vt100_codes_news.txt) to reposition the cursor on a higher line, then overdraw it with your updated status.

Comment: The link is broken. Here's web archive's version: http://web.archive.org/web/20110103061220/http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~shuford/terminal/vt100_codes_news.txt

Answer (score 0):

The [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library offers powerful control for console UIs.