# Dynamic multiple lines refresh printing in Python

Tags: python, json, dynamic, printing

I am completely new to Python and there's something that I can't figure out how to do.

**What I want do to:**

I would like to be able to dynamically rewrite the output on multiple lines in the console. I have seen many solutions for a single line output but not that many for multiple lines. The following threads on Stack Overflow are similar, but didn't solve completely my problem (I'll explain later why):

[Python - Rewrite multiple lines in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

[Dynamic refresh printing of multiprocessing or multithreading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944959/dynamic-refresh-printing-of-multiprocessing-or-multithreading-in-python)

Also, I would like to be able to redirect the output to a file or a pipe (let's say that in the solutions provided above, I would run ./script.py > out.txt and if I interrupt that, I want the intermediate progress bar to be in the output file).

**Why do I want to do that?**

I am trying to parse a continuous Json stream which looks something like that:

```
{
...valid Json data block...
},{
...Another valid Json data block...
}, etc...
```

What I would like in the end would be something like (the process for which I need help is the filter to the only one Json block):

```
./generate-stream | ./filter-single-view | ./json-processing
```

NB: The fact that I'm using Json doesn't really matter for my problem, I'm mostly saying it to give you a context. The idea is simply to have a piping of scripts that generates multiple data, filters it to have one data at a time and then processes this data.

I have already parsed the stream to have my Json block in a string that I would like to print (and then print the next one that would rewrite on it). 
Example of a dynamic refresh:

```
{
"i": 0
}
```

Console output step 1 (I already have all that information stored in a string)

```
{
"i": 1
}
```

Console output step 2

```
{
"i": 2
}
```

Console output step 3, etc...

Hence, the answer to the first thread doesn't work with my problem because I can't output the result and the answer to the second doesn't work for the same reason + this way to clear the screens messes up the data, which can't be used properly in the next process. Another thing that would solve my problem would be to **find a way to ignore continuously the clear screen character** (I've tried ignoring the first characters, it worked for the first input and then was all messed up).

Please tell me if something was unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you want to make something like "top" at the terminal using curses.  I would ask there are so many other GUI's that have this problem solved.  I would suggest using one of those.  Since you are using json I would highly suggest the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not quite sure of what you mean... My goal here is not to make a GUI (if I can avoid using one, it'd actually be better), curses came up as a solution to similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem!

I told you the stream format above, don't worry about the parsing details. This code parses the stream and displays the Json data singularly

```
    import sys
    import json
    import os

    def main(): 
        json_string=""
        try:
            while True:
                line=sys.stdin.readline()
                if line!="},{\n":
                    json_string=json_string+line
                    continue
                else:
                    #Output singular Json data
                    json_string=json_string+"}\n"
                    json_data=json.loads(json_string)
                    json.dump(json_data, sys.stdout) 
                    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
                    sys.stdout.flush() 
                    json_string="{\n" 
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.stdin.close()
            print "Interrupted by user. Bye!"  

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Now, I want this singular data to be read in another script piped behind (stdin). I didn't really understand why, but any readline would be blocking. Thus, I implemented the following

```
    import sys
    import json
    import os

    k = 0
    parsing=False
    try:
        buff = ''
        while True:
            #The 2 following functions are blocking
            #buff= sys.stdin.readline()
            #buff = json.load(sys.stdin)
            buff += sys.stdin.read(1)
            if buff.endswith('{'):
                parsing=True;
                k+=1
            if buff.endswith('}'):
                k-=1
            if k==0 and parsing:
                print buff
                #The first 7 characters clear the screen
                data=json.loads(buff[7:])
                buff = ''
                parsing=False

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       sys.stdout.flush()
       pass
```

Please let me know if you have any comment on that.