# progressbars inside multiprocessing calls overwriting each other on display

Tags: python, progress-bar, command-line-interface, python-multiprocessing

I'm using progressbar 3.6.2, and getting incorrect display output when running multiple progressbars simultaneously.  They write "on top" of each other.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import progressbar

    def run_many:
      p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count(), maxtasksperchild=1)
      results = p.map(run_one, args_list)
      p.close()
      p.join()

    def run_one:
       with progressbar.Progressbar(max_value=5000) as bar: 
           for i in range(5000):
               do_heavy_lifting(i)
               bar.update(i)
```

I get output that is **one** line long but oscillates between something that looks like

`30% (1500 of 5000) |#######------------| Elapsed Time: 0:00:39 Time: 0:00:39`

and

`29% (1400 of 5000) |######-------------| Elapsed Time: 0:00:39 Time: 0:00:39`

as each thread updates its own progress bar asynchronously.  It looks like they're just displaying on top of each other.

Blindly inserting a line-break before going into the loop doesn't work (no surprise); what's a better option?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because more than 1 process is writing to the stdout, so they overwrite each other.

What you have to do is:

1. create a multiprocessing queue `results = mp.Queue()`
2. feed it results from within your child processes like `results.put((mp.current_process(), status))`
3. from the main process you have to read this data `process_id, status = results.get()`
4. display a progress bar for each process

Here is a perfect code that I based of when  writing my multiprocessing progress monitor: [Dynamic refresh printing of multiprocessing or multithreading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944959/dynamic-refresh-printing-of-multiprocessing-or-multithreading-in-python/13946863#13946863)