# Python command line print on the same lines

Tags: python, shell, terminal

There are many questions relating to printing on the same line but there aren't any for printing multiple lines on the same line within the terminal.

For example:

```
ogeno@OH-ogeno-MBP:~|⇒ python my_script.py
Process 1: 5%
Process 2: 14%
Process 3: 55%
```

I want the progress of these processes to update on the same line rather than printing over and over again. I have looked at other questions that say to use the return carriage character `\r` and `sys.stdout.flush()` but it doesn't seem to change the caret to go up a line, just to the end of the  current line.

EDIT: My question is different because it's to do with printing MULTIPLE lines on the same lines in the terminal. It's easy if it's just one line.

Comment: please share a code snippet to see how you are handling this from my_script.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Rewrite multiple lines in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: The sane solution to this is to have your controlling process collect the status info and print it.

Comment: @glls I'm not handling this. It's just an example of what I want

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'd prefer not to use that curses module. I want to just do it in plain ole python

Comment: @pvg It still needs to be printing in the same console. It doesn't matter which process does it. But the information needs to update ON THE SAME LINE rather than printing again.

Comment: Ok, then what's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727155/multiline-progress-bars

Comment: @pvg It's on one line, which is easy. Mine is multiple lines that need to print on the same line - big difference.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'll take a look at that, seems like a really dirty workaround though... clearing the entire console :(

Comment: @Ogen I was looking at aaren's solution. But generally, I guess, the system-dependent nature of the task makes it hard in simple good ole Python.

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's just a shame that it's so easy to do if it's just one line, but a lot harder if it's multiple lines. I thought maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Right but what is stopping you from collecting the output from multiple lines and printing it on one line?

Comment: Is it that you want to repeatedly print on the same line?

Comment: @pvg Because it would look ugly all on one line don't you agree? And yes I want to print on the same lines so the user can just see the progress updating in the same place in the terminal

Comment: Ah I see. There is really no platform-independent way to do that. ncurses can cover the unix-y case.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [ANSI escape-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) `"\033[F"` for going to the beginning of the previous line. The following worked well in all my terminals, just writing to the next two lines from the current terminal position:

```
import time
import sys

progress_1 = 'Process 1: {}%'
progress_2 = 'Process 2: {}%'
print
print

for i in range(100):
    sys.stdout.write('\033[F')
    sys.stdout.write('\033[F')
    print(progress_1.format(i))
    print(progress_2.format(i))
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: That's giving me a weird result when I run it. Some of the print statements are being written above my main terminal line.

Comment: Then the screen clearing isn't working. I assume you are not working on Linux.

Comment: I'm on Mac. Regardless, I don't want the screen cleared, is there any way to get around this

Comment: @Ogen I added some more system-independent terminal clearing code.

Comment: @Ogen I added some code that should work without clearing the terminal.

Comment: It's just printing a lot of lines now unfortunately. I had code similar to this that didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by using backspace. Following is the sample code that will print the percentage on the same line.

```
import time
print "Work in progress(0%%)", # Python 2 print without newline
for work_done in range(10):
    print "\b\b\b\b\b%2d%%)" % work_done, # Backspace then overwrite
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That's not doing what I want

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.7 you can use,

```
print 2%, 3% # Using comma will print it in same line
```

for python 3.x

```
print('2%', end=" ")
```

Or you can use sys.stdout.write for doing it with sys.stdout.flush()
Please check my below code, I have created a demo progress bar.

```
"""ProgressBar Module."""

import sys
import time


class ProgressBar(object):
    """Main class for the ProgressBa."""

    DEFAULT_BAR_LENGTH = float(30)

    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        """Init for the class."""
        self.end = ProgressBar.DEFAULT_BAR_LENGTH
        self.start = start
        self.step = step
        self.total = self.end - self.start
        self.counts = self.total / self.step
        self._barLength = ProgressBar.DEFAULT_BAR_LENGTH

        self.set_level(self.start)
        self._plotted = False

    def set_level_old(self, level, initial=False):
        """Setting Level."""
        self._level = level
        if level < self.start:
            self._level = self.start
        if level > self.end:
            self._level = self.end

        self._ratio = float(
            self._level - self.start) / float(self.end - self.start)
        self._levelChars = int(self._ratio * self._barLength)

    def set_level(self, level, initial=False):
        """Setting Level."""
        self._level = level
        if level < self.start:
            self._level = self.start
        if level > self.end:
            self._level = self.end

        self._ratio = float(self._level) / float(self._barLength)
        self._levelChars = int(self._ratio * self._barLength) * self.step

    def plot_progress(self):
        """Plotting the bar."""
        sys.stdout.write("\r  %3i%%  |%s%s|" % (
            int(self._ratio * self.step * 100.0),
            u'\u2588' * int(self._levelChars),
            ' ' * int(self._barLength - self._levelChars),
        ))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self._plotted = True

    def set_and_plot(self, level):
        """Call the plot."""
        old_chars = self._levelChars
        self.set_level(level)
        if (not self._plotted) or (old_chars != self._levelChars):
            self.plot_progress()

    def __del__(self):
        """Del for the class."""
        sys.stdout.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pb = ProgressBar(0, 1)

    curProgress = 0
    pb.plot_progress()
    while curProgress <= pb.counts:
        pb.set_and_plot(curProgress)
        curProgress += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)

    del pb
```